# Why can't I pull from my fresh GH repo? (error: unrelated histories)

Tags: git

Someone created an empty `GitHub` repo for me and added a README.md file in it. In the meantime I started working on my project.

Now I want to start pushing on this repo so I did `git init` followed by `git remote add origin https://github.com/whatever/my_project.git`.

But then when I do `git pull origin master` to get sync with the repo and start pushing to it, I get this error message:

```
* branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because both the github repo and the local repo have initial commits with no parent. It cannot reconcile how to connect them. What I would do in this situation is manually copy the readme to my local repo and do a force push:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: That sounds like a hack to me, is there a non-hacky way or is that the only way?

Comment: Yeah, see answers in linked question.

Comment: I actually prefer the forced-push for this particular situation - there is no reason to clutter up the repository with the default GitHub `README.md`-only commit. You might want to add this answer to that question. (Also, "force push" seems appropriate for May the 4th... :-) )

Comment: Good idea. Did that.